# Increment setInterval value dynamically

Tags: javascript, setinterval

```
<script>
let increment = 0;
const interval = 1000;
let delay = () => {


    increment += 1;
    return interval * increment;


};

setInterval(
    () => console.log('Hello World. ' + delay() / 1000),

    delay()
);
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong here, although in the console every time I can see an increment in value, but why it is not delaying console output w.r.t increment?

Is there any possibility to change the interval directly using a single line of code without writing an extra function?

Thank you!

Comment: you want `setTimeout`, not `setInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

`setInterval` - 2nd parameter takes the number of seconds. So since you are initially calling `delay()` it will return 1000 the first time and use that as the interval.

If you want to change interval each time, you will have to call `clearInterval` and call `setInterval` again.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

```js
let increment = 0;
const interval = 1000;
let delay = () => {


    increment += 1;
    console.log(interval + ", " + increment);
    return interval * increment;


};

setInterval(
    () => console.log('Hello World. ' + delay() / 1000),

    delay()
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution, is there any way without using clearInterval?